# Correctly Writing A Quadratic Differential Equation Solver in Python

Tags: python, solver, differential-equations, nonlinear-functions

I would like to plot a particle's path through phase space using only the Hamiltonian
`E = p**2 + U(x)`, where p=dx/dt. And so for a constant energy E (given by initial values x0, p0), I can restrict what p is for a given x.

So the code in time for solving the path is

```
x = x0
p = p0
E = H(x0, p0)
t_step = 0
dt = 0.01
    
while t_step < tmax:
    x = x + p*t_step
    p = (E - (H(x, p0) - p0**2))**0.5
    t_step += dt
```

Don't mind the code as much as the part I'm worried about, which is `p = (E - (H(x,p0) - p0**2))**0.5`. The problem with this is that p, the derivative of x, is going to always be positive, which cannot be right.

But as far as I know, there isn't just a way to slap on a negative when it should be negative. Is there a different numerical method to solve an equation like this that will take that into account, or (fingers crossed) is there something more simple I can do to adjust the equation of p?

Comment: Hi, your code is incomplete. Fix the imports and the initial values. If you are using `sympy` you can add the **assumption** to be positive, smt like `p = Derivative(x, t, positive=True)`

Comment: Your use of `t_step` is wrong, it should be `dt` in the Euler update. // One can expect `p` to be smooth, so the second difference `p(t-dt)-2*p(t)+p(t+dt)` should be small. Thus set the sign of the square root according to the sign of `2*p(t)-p(t-dt)`. This is not perfect, but should work well enough for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @LutzLehmann This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for! And thanks for the looking out for the t_step, missed it during some edits of variable names. It worked, however now it has shown me a new problem, unrelated to this one. Thanks for the help!